# How do I set a Type TSomething at run time in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I am writting a function that takes a parameter and that parameter requires a Type of TEntity. I want to be able to pass it a specific Type during runtime but I am having trouble getting it to compile:

```
public LoadOperation LoadQuery(EntityQuery<???> query)
        {
            LoadOperation loadOperation = DomainContext.Load(query,LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent, false);
            return loadOperation;
        }
```

The code that wont compile looks like this:

```
EntityQuery<Person> q = DomainContext.GetPerson();
LoadQuery(q);
```

I have tried different things to make this work but am at a loss. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what your DomainContext.Load() function looks like:

```
public LoadOperation LoadQuery<T>(EntityQuery<T> query)
{
    LoadOperation loadOperation = DomainContext.Load(query,LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent, false);
    return loadOperation;
}
```

And then still use it exactly like you did before:

```
EntityQuery<Person> q = DomainContext.GetPerson();
LoadQuery(q);
```

The type system should infer you mean the `LoadQuery<Person>()` version of the function from the argument.

Unfortunately, I suspect this will also mean some revision to the aforementioned Load() function.

Comment: The load function is part of WCF RIA services, so it is not mine. Would the only way to do what I am trying to do be to override that function?

Comment: This issue is that type of the first parameter to the function: can you pass any generic `EntityQuery<T>` to it?  I'm guessing not.  If you can modify the function so that you can, that's good.  Since you can't, you'll need a way to massage your query variable into something this function will accept.

Comment: I still didnt get it to work but your answer explained a lot of what is going on. I marked it as answered because it is exactly right, the problem is in the Load() function and so that is where I need to focus. Since Load() requires TEntity I will need to figure out how to modify it to take T or massage my query to be TEntity.